# converting local date, time and timezone values to utc timezone in php

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, timezone

I am working on an iPhone app where I am getting date and time(separate) from user and submitting it to my php web service. php web service is then supposed to take this date and time and save it to utc timezone. I have read that I will also require local timezone in php file to convert it to utc. I am getting 'Asia/Kolkata (IST) offset 1980' as my timezone value in my iPhone application and can send it to php file. Now how will I convert date, time and timezone to utc date.

I have to convert the date to utc format so that I can query my table to get me data which is not past local time.

Thanks in advance

Regards
Pankaj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`setTimeZone`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php) to convert the timezone from whatever the user sends to UTC:

```
    $utz = new DateTimeZone($input['timezone']);
    $udt = new DateTime($input['date'].' '.$input['time'], $utz);
    $udt->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));

    echo $input['date'].' '.$input['time'].' '.$input['timezone'].' is '.$udt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')." UTC\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

check out [PHP DateTime();](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php)

Essentially you'll want to handle it somewhat like below.

```
$date = new DateTime($dateFromiPhone);
$date->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone("UTC"));
```

And then use `$date->format();` to format for your desired usage